# modify the TextBlock value when click on Button of each ListViewItem

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have this code for my ListView:

```
 <ListView  x:Name="listme">
 <ListView.ItemTemplate >
   <DataTemplate >
     <Grid>
       ...
      <Button Background="{Binding ButtonColor}"  x:Name="btnStar" 
Click="btnStar_Click" Tag={Binding}>
           <Image/>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=all_like}" x:Name="liketext" />
      </Button>
     </Grid>
   </DataTemplate >
 </ListView.ItemTemplate >
</ListView >
```

I have 2 ListviewItems,each one has a "BtnStar" Button,each Button has a "liketext" TextBlock,one of those TextBlocks works only,per example when I click on btnStar of ListViewItem1 it modifies the TextBlock value of ListViewItem2's TextBlock,I can't modify the Text of TextBlock of ListViewItem1 when I click on BtnStar of ListViewItem1,this is my code:

```
 ObservableCollection<Locals> Locals = new ObservableCollection<Locals>();
     public async void getListePerSearch()
    {
        try
        {
            UriString2 = "URL";
            var http = new HttpClient();
            http.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
            var response = await http.GetStringAsync(UriString2);
            var rootObject1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NvBarberry.Models.RootObject>(response);

           foreach (var item in rootObject1.locals)
                {
                    Item listItem = new Item();
                    if (listItem.all_like == null)
                        {
                            listItem.all_like = "0";
                        }

                listme.ItemsSource = Locals;
   }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
                {
                    var btn = sender as Button;
                    var item = btn.Tag as Locals;
                    item.all_like = liketext.Text;
                    liketext.Text = (int.Parse(item.all_like) + 1).ToString();
                    }
```

Locals.cs:

```
public class Locals : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int id_local { get; set; }
    public string all_like { get; set; }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

so,how can I modify the value of the TextBlock when I click on the BtnStar Button of each ListViewItem
thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. first of all you need use Binding approach in xaml apps.

your class Locals implement INotifyPropertyChanged but is bad implemented.
Please check this example:

```
public string someProperty {get;set;}
public string SomeProperty 

{

get
 {
   return someProperty;
 }
 set
 {
   someProperty =value;
   NotifyPropertyChanged("SomeProperty");
 }
}
```

in your textblock you have Text={Binding SomeProperty}

you need to add Mode= TwoWay

Text={Binding SomeProperty, Mode= TwoWay}

finally in your click method 
btnStar_Click

you need to do something like this:

```
var btn = sender as Button;
var local= btn.DataContext as Local;
local.SomeProperty= "my new value"
```

If you have implemented correctly INotifyPropertyChanged in your model you will see the change in your UI.

that's all.

Please mark this answer if it's useful for you!

Best Regards.

Comment: Please mark this answer if it's useful for you! Best Regards.